# Redis use keys query keys,CPU run high more than 20%, I only use single redis

Tags: spring-mvc, redis, key

I use single redis for my application, 
my connect redis through Spring MVC for my backgroud server. 
I use the command keys like XXXX* to query key in Redis DB. 
My Redis DB has only 20000 record.
I find CPU run exceed 20% and query delayed 1000ms. 
How I can deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is single-threaded. `KEYS` command iterates all keys to match the given pattern, and that takes lots of time, especially when there're too many keys in the database.

In the meanwhile, Redis is blocked, and it CANNOT process any new requests. So your new query will be delayed until the `KEYS` command finishes.

**Solution**:

Replace the `KEYS` command with `SCAN` command, and incrementally iterate keys in database.